# Does billing of ACI continue to happen even when my python code is waiting for messages on service bus subscription?

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics, azure-container-instances, azure-sdk-python, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am have simple python code which subscribes to a service bus subscription. I have containerized this and deployed as part of ACI on Azure. 
If message arrives on service bus subscription, the code is executed, executes it logic and then waits indefinitely for another message from appear.

The code is what Azure has provided in its documentation for python sdk [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/receive_subscription.py)

Since ACI is serverless and bills/second, just wanted a confirmation if I'll get billed even if it is not executing my code and waiting for message for appear on topic/subscription (event-based) ?

Comment: Any more questions? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Is there anything unexpected in the answer? I didn't see any updates and you also didn't accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. It will cost if there is anyone container instance in the running state. Until you stop all the container instance, then the cost will stop. So even if your code is waiting, but the instance is running.